# Is it possible to add shipping tracking number in a batch system?

Tags: magento

Imagine **client A** placing an order for 5 items in an e-commerce website (through Magento which collects the information and sends it to the warehouse which happens in the background). The website records the order and processes this information to the warehouse.The warehouse collects the information and after processing and shipping the product, provide the **client A** with a shipping information with tracking and carrier number.

My question is,

**I want to update the tracking number inside Magento for each product separately because the shipping time might differ for each product.** If the customer places a bulk order and receives the products one by one but with the same tracking number it will be misleading as the customer might think all the products will arrive on the same day and the customer might be dissatisfied.

**How can I place a separate tracking number for each product using Magento?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has this all built into the API. You can create a new shipment against an order and specify the items on the order which have been shipped along with a unique tracking code per shipment. So one order can have as many shipments as you require. Bundle kits may be a little troublesome but there is an option in the config to handle part shipments of bundle kits. Check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.create.html for the API documentation. We have a java app that picks up all of our delivery manifest info on a 10 minute cycle from our back office and then makes SOAP requests to create shipment notifications. This also sends an email to the customer along with the tracking code and if you add in your courier through a custom module you can also make it so that magento handles your couriers tracking link which can be accessed from the My Account area for the customer and it is also included in the email notification that the customer gets per shipment notification.

Comment: You can create SOAP requests using PHP. See the documentation for examples (in fact all examples in the documentation are done with PHP and SOAP.) There is a full PHP working example here if you look: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/salesOrderShipment.html

Comment: P.S. Soap is a protocol much like HTTP not a language. You use the SOAP protocol to send xml messages/commands to the web-site and get back an XML response. Generally you can make SOAP requests using most languages these day including PHP, Java, .Net etc.